# ¿Cómo agregar múltiples "Title" a mi TabbedPage?

Tags: android, c#, xamarin.forms

Mis estimados, tengo un problema con los "Title" del Tabbedpage, cuando ejecuto con el emulador de Android esto es lo que me aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

...como se ve no aparece los "Title" de la lista de mi class, les dejo mis class creadas:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Text;
using PluralSight_XamarinForms.SamplesPages;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace PluralSight_XamarinForms.Samples
{
    public class ButtonsPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ButtonsPage()
        {
            Title = "Types of Pages";
            var button1 = new Button
            {
                Text = "Simple Page"
            };
            button1.Clicked += (e, o) =>
              {
                  Navigation.PushAsync(new MyItems1(classBase.GetNames().First()));
              };

```
        var button2 = new Button
        {
            Text = "Master detail"
        };
        button2.Clicked += (e, o) =>
          {
              Navigation.PushAsync(new MasterDetailItems());
          };

        var button3 = new Button
        {
            Text = "Master Binding"
        };
        button3.Clicked += (o, e) =>
          {
              Navigation.PushAsync(new MasterDetailItemsDB());
          };

        var button4 = new Button
        {
            Text = "TabbedPage"
        };
        button4.Clicked += (o, e) =>
          {
              var page = new TabbedPage();
              page.Title = "Courses Pages";

              foreach (var myItemsDB in classBase.GetNames())
              {
                  var courseitems = new MyItems1DB();
                  courseitems.BindingContext = myItemsDB;
                  page.Children.Add(courseitems);
              }

              Navigation.PushAsync(page);
          };


        BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
            Spacing = 10,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Children =
            {
                button1,
                button2,
                button3,
                button4
            }
        };

    }
}
```

}

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using PluralSight_XamarinForms.Samples;

namespace PluralSight_XamarinForms.SamplesPages
{
    class MyItems1DB : ContentPage
    {
        public MyItems1DB()
        {
            BackgroundColor = Color.Aqua;

```
        var labelTitle = new Label
        {
            //Text = myItem.Title,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Red,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
        };
        labelTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

        var labelDescription = new Label
        {
            //Text = myItem.Description,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Yellow,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
        };
        labelDescription.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Description");

        var labelAutor = new Label
        {
            //Text = myItem.Autor,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Blue,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic
        };
        labelAutor.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Autor");

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Spacing = 10,
            Children =
            {
               labelTitle,
               labelDescription,
               labelAutor,
            }
        };

    }
}
```

}

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PluralSight_XamarinForms.Samples
{
    class classBase
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
    public static List<classBase>GetNames()
    {
        var myListAdd = new List<classBase>();
        myListAdd.Add(new classBase
        {

            Title = "Building in Xamarin",
            Description = "Aprendiendo de xamarin forms, " +
                          "novedades de las mejores plataformas todo en un proyecto",
            Autor = "Daniel Monetelli",
        });

        myListAdd.Add(new classBase
        {
            Title = "Hola xamarin",
            Description = " mi nuevo metodo en xamarin",
            Autor = "Lorens Mau"
        });

        myListAdd.Add(new classBase
        {
            Title = "Que jodidos",
            Description = " Los chistes mas picantes",
            Autor = "Nicolas Santa"
        });

        myListAdd.Add(new classBase
        {
            Title = "El picaflor viene",
            Description = "Obra que trata de como la gente mancha el honor de otros",
            Autor = "Gasw Mewt"
        });

        return myListAdd;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: arregla la maquetación del código para que se visualice correctamente, para ello edita la pregunta y el icono {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos basicamente tu error es por que tienes las líneas de text comentadas,

```
var labelTitle = new Label
        {
            Text = myItem.Title,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Red,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
        };
        labelTitle.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

        var labelDescription = new Label
        {
            Text = myItem.Description,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Yellow,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
        };
        labelDescription.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Description");

        var labelAutor = new Label
        {
           Text = myItem.Autor,
            FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
            TextColor = Color.Blue,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold | FontAttributes.Italic
        };
```

Comment: Estan en forma de comentario por que lo use sin un binding directo

Comment: El Método SetBinding es lo mismo que usar myItem.Title